# javafx repeat complex Fxml inside pane

Tags: javafx, fxml, repeat

I have design a complex fxml node with scene builder,
I want to repeat it in fxml file, so create a seperate fxml with the complex design, and I use the FXMLLoader , 
If I load the FXML  in the initialize() method I get a infinity loop , the initialize function runs again and again.
If I put the fxml loader inside a button event, it works as expected but every time I call the fxml loader , the initialize function runs again,
So as I see I miss all the data ? 
Is there any way to add context dynamic without running the initialize method again ?

```
FXMLLoader Relay_Output_Loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Relay_Output_Controller.fxml"));  //Get FXML Loader
        BorderPane_Relay_Output =  Relay_Output_Loader.load();                                                          //Get default Pane
        Stack_Pane_Main_Controller.getChildren().add(BorderPane_Relay_Output);
```

Comment: Are you using the same controller class for both fxmls? `initialize` is inevitably invoked for every fxml loaded that uses the controller.

Comment: no I dont use seperate controller in this case.
So that is the problem ? I must create a seperate controller for the "complex" fxml ?
I have use this when I create menu screens , and I load them on a stack pane

Comment: Yes, it's a problem. If loading a fxml involves loading the same fxml again without any termination condition, you get infinite recursion -> StackOverflow. Furthermore the way you load the fxml suggests you let `FXMLLoader` create the controller instances. This means you'll get 1 controller instance for every fxml loaded with does not help for communication between the fxmls...

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: thank you for your help, my mistake it was that I was use the same controller! works as expected now